# How to edit file in paramiko after searching a pattern

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

Im opening a file in remote server through ssh session using paramiko ,and then i search for pattern in that file and after getting the pattern ,i need to add a text in the next line after the pattern's line.and then after some time i want to remove that particular text.
Any recommendation would be highly appreciated.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='...', username='root', password='')             
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("en")
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cat /var/etc/copy.xml")
```

Comment: You'd be better off using sftp rather than plain ssh. sftp has operations to read and write remote files.

Comment: or execute linux sed with your patterns on that file.